# How can i delete related values?

Tags: laravel

Newbie to laravel here! I have Category table and Formation table Both are related each category have many formation and each formation belongs to category, What i am trying to do is each time a delete a category all the formation that's are related to that category must be deleted also.

This is My Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    function formations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Formation');
    }

    protected $fillable =['name','description'];

}
```

And this is My Formation Model

```
class Formation extends Model
{
    function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category',"category_id");
    }
}
```

This is how i am deleting My Category

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $category->delete();
    return redirect()->route('category.index');
}
```

What code should i add so that when i delete any category all the formation are related to are deleted too ? i hope my question is clear and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but can't you solve this on database level by adding a foreign key that on delete cascades? I know this is not a real answer since you want to know how to do this in Laravel, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: Yeah it is possible to solve it with and foreign key constraint, but it is not recommend, because sometimes it could be possible, that it isn't a wanted behavior to delete the relations

Comment: @JulianStark Yeah exacly. That's why this isn't an answer, but just wondering if for his case a foreign key with on delete cascading would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by delete all relations before deleting the category with `$category->formations()->delete();`

Or you can add it to your model by listening to the deleting event

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($category) {
             $category->formations()->delete();
        });
    }

    public function formations()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Formation');
    }
}
```